Recursive async function: future cannot be sent between threads safely
I want to make a tool to iterate over a specific directory. It will read the video duration and resolution using ffmpeg when finding a video file, and that's a time-consuming work. Therefore I want to use async functions to improve the performance. However, it cannot pass the compilation check. Here is the minimal reproducible example:
use std::sync::Arc;

use tokio::sync::Mutex;

#[derive(Debug)]
enum Entry {
    Dir(Vec<Entry>),
    File,
}

async fn iterate_dir() -> Entry {
    let entries = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Vec::<Entry>::new()));
    let mut tasks = tokio::task::JoinSet::<()>::new();
    for _entry in 0..10 {
        let entries_cloned = entries.clone();
        if rand::random::<f32>() > 0.8 {
            // It's directory
            tasks.spawn(async move {
                entries_cloned.lock().await.push(iterate_dir().await);
            });
        } else {
            // It's file
            entries_cloned.lock().await.push(Entry::File);
        }
    }
    tasks.join_all().await;
    Entry::Dir(Arc::try_unwrap(entries).unwrap().into_inner())
}

And a more concise example after trimming all statements irrelevant to the error message:
async fn test() {
    tokio::spawn(async move {
        test().await;
    });
}

The diagnostic message are both like:
error: future cannot be sent between threads safely
   --> src/main.rs:2:5
    |
2   | /     tokio::spawn(async move {
3   | |         test().await;
4   | |     });
    | |______^ future created by async block is not `Send`
    |
    = note: cannot satisfy `impl Future<Output = ()>: Send`
note: future is not `Send` as it awaits another future which is not `Send`
   --> src/main.rs:3:9
    |
3   |         test().await;
    |         ^^^^^^ await occurs here on type `impl Future<Output = ()>`, which is not `Send`
note: required by a bound in `tokio::spawn`
   --> C:\Users\pc\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\tokio-1.40.0\src\task\spawn.rs:167:21
    |
165 |     pub fn spawn<F>(future: F) -> JoinHandle<F::Output>
    |            ----- required by a bound in this function
166 |     where
167 |         F: Future + Send + 'static,
    |                     ^^^^ required by this bound in `spawn`

I've googled this question before posting this question, but the answers I got are mostly about adding + Send to your Result<(), Box<dyn Error>>. However there's no such statement in my code. So what should I do to solve this problem?

I don't know much about rust but that sounds like a particularly bad idea. For one: you are probably conflating "async" and "concurrent". Second: You might be way better off going iterative rather than recursive. I don't know if that's what's canonical for rust, though. In other languages I'd avoid this and especially the combination of async and recursion if ever possible.

This is probably because of this bug. The workaround is to replace the async functions with functions returning impl Future + Send and put an async block directly inside:
playground
use std::future::Future;
use std::sync::Arc;

use tokio::sync::Mutex;

#[derive(Debug)]
enum Entry {
    Dir(Vec<Entry>),
    File,
}

fn iterate_dir() -> impl Future<Output=Entry> + Send {async {
    let entries = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Vec::<Entry>::new()));
    let mut tasks = tokio::task::JoinSet::<()>::new();
    for _entry in 0..10 {
        let entries_cloned = entries.clone();
        // let entries.cloned
        if rand::random::<f32>() > 0.8 {
            // It's directory
            tasks.spawn(async move {
                entries_cloned.lock().await.push(iterate_dir().await);
            });
        } else {
            // It's file
            entries_cloned.lock().await.push(Entry::File);
        }
    }
    tasks.join_all().await;
    Entry::Dir(Arc::try_unwrap(entries).unwrap().into_inner())
}}

playground
use std::future::Future;

fn test() -> impl Future<Output = ()> + Send {async {
    tokio::spawn(async move {
        test().await;
    });
}}


Thanks. I finally solved this problem by following your instruction!
